# ClassCastException when using TreeMap

Tags: java, treemap

I have a `TreeMap<Integer, TreeMap<int[][], Integer>> jungle`. When I try to execute the statements

```
TreeMap<int[][], Integer> tempMap = new TreeMap();
int[][] matrix = {{1}};
tempMap.put(matrix, 4);
```

this last line gives me the

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [[I cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.Comparable at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.compare
```

exception. Am I not allowed to use an `int[][]` as a key in a `treeMap`?

Comment: If you use a key that doesn't implement Comparable , then you need to provide a Comparator to the constructor.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Do you mean that it has no way of knowing how to compare two 2D arrays unless I tell it explicitly how to do so?

Comment: That's it, there is dozens of ways to order 2D-arrays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html) is to have an ordered collection

> A Red-Black tree based NavigableMap implementation. The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

You must pass a `Comparator` that deals with `int[][]`; here an example with one that sorted based on the full sum of the array

```
class Custom2DArrayComparator implements Comparator<int[][]> {

    private static int sum(int[][] v) {
        return Arrays.stream(v).map(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr).sum())
                               .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(int[][] o1, int[][] o2) {
        return Integer.compare(sum(o1), sum(o2));
    }
}
```

Use

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeMap<int[][], Integer> tempMap = new TreeMap<>(new Custom2DArrayComparator());
    int[][] matrix = {{1}};
    tempMap.put(matrix, 4);
}
```

---

You can use the anonymous class to avoid creating a one outside

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeMap<int[][], Integer> tempMap = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(int[][] o1, int[][] o2) {
            return Integer.compare(sum(o1), sum(o2));
        }

        int sum(int[][] v) {
            return Arrays.stream(v).map(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr).sum())
                .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
        }
    });
    int[][] matrix = {{1}};
    tempMap.put(matrix, 4);
}
```

Comment: Do I have to create a separate class or can I just implement the compare method in the same class?

Comment: @Junglemath you can even use a `anonymous class`, look my edit ;)

Comment: I'm a bit confused. In my current class I added a method ```public int compare(int[][] A, int[][] B){ return 0;}``` and it says that "method does not override or implement a method from a supertype".?

Comment: @Junglemath It's not in the current class that you may add the method, you have to have a dedicated class for the comparator (like my first code) OR implement it as anonymous as the second

Comment: I created a new class ```CustomCompare``` like in your first example, and I am still getting the same exception.

Comment: @Junglemath Can't see how. https://repl.it/@azro352/AcrobaticHiddenPhysics#Main.java works fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227076/discussion-between-junglemath-and-azro).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to implement your own logic in order for your key to be Comparable, as Johannes' comment points out. You could create a class that implements `Comparator` and pass it as argument at the initialization of the `TreeMap`.

Note that the *default/overriden* **`compare`** method would also be valid, as `arrays` are just `Objects`.

You could even implement all the logics for non-comparable `Object` keys you wish to insert in different `Maps` in a single class:

```
public class NonCompObjectKeyComparator implements Comparator<Object> 
{         
    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) 
    {
       if (o1 instanceof int[][])
       {
         //((int[][])o1),((int[][])o2)//
       }
       else if (o1 instanceof String[])
       {
         //((String[])o1),((String[])o2)//
       }
       else if (o1 instanceof <OtherNonComparableObjType>)
       {
         //...
       }
       //...          
       return 0;
    }
}
```

And then you got your **`überComparator`** there:

```
Comparator<Object> maCompa = new NonCompObjectKeyComparator();

TreeMap<int[][], Integer> tempMap   = new TreeMap(maCompa);
TreeMap<String[], String> sArrayMap = new TreeMap(maCompa);

int[][] matrix = {{1}};
tempMap.put(matrix, 4);

String[] sKey = {"a"};
sArrayMap.put(sKey, "anotherWierdMap");
```

---

In order to create an specific `int[][]` comparator, just:

```
public class CustomKeyComparator implements Comparator<int[][]> {    

    public int compare(int[][] a1, int[][] a2) {
        //your logic here
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and

```
TreeMap<int[][], Integer> tempMap = new TreeMap(new CustomKeyComparator());
int[][] matrix = {{1}};
tempMap.put(matrix, 4);
```

---